# Why are yarn and npm using the Incorrect Node version for package installation and running my react app despite NVM having only the correct version?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, package.json

Some context, I am building a react application based on a UI kit I purchased which works fine sometimes and other times demonstrates this weird behavior. As explained above, upon running npm install or yarn install I get this issue:

```
error d3-chord@3.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12". Got "10.19.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

On NVM I only have Node version 19.8.1 installed and have confirmed that this is the node version in use.
When I try the command `node -v` I get the response `v19.8.1`.

In addition, there have been numerous instances where I have managed to get the system to work, but each time I must find some different solution to what ultimately is the same problem which is the node version.

Below are the two package.json files I am using for the two projects where I have this issue present in.

Project 1

```
{
  "name": "datta-able-react-hook-reactstrap-js",
  "version": "17.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "10.0.0.130",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@tanem/react-nprogress": "^4.0.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "firebase": "^8.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "nib-core": "2.7.16",
    "npm": "^7.6.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-nvd3": "^0.5.7",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.8",
    "rodal": "^1.8.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8128 start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Project 2

```
{
  "name": "datta-able-react-hook-reactstrap-js",
  "version": "17.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "10.0.0.130",
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.1.8",
    "@amcharts/amcharts5-geodata": "^5.0.2",
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.20.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "33.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^4.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@tanem/react-nprogress": "^4.0.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.33.2",
    "aphrodite": "^2.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.12",
    "deni-react-treeview": "^1.1.11",
    "echarts": "^5.3.1",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "firebase": "^8.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "highcharts": "^10.0.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jodit": "^3.15.3",
    "jodit-react": "^1.2.10",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "match-sorter": "6.3.1",
    "namor": "^2.0.3",
    "nib-core": "2.7.16",
    "npm": "^7.6.3",
    "pnotify": "4.0.0",
    "prism-react-renderer": "0.1.7",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.5",
    "rc-tooltip": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-animated-tree": "^1.0.10",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap4-form-validation": "^1.0.10",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-compound-timer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-cropper": "^2.1.8",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-datetime": "^3.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dual-listbox": "^2.2.0",
    "react-flot": "^1.3.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-image-video-lightbox": "2.0.1",
    "react-image-zoom-hook": "^0.1.13",
    "react-images": "^1.1.7",
    "react-images-texts-videos": "^0.0.7",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-joyride": "^2.3.2",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.16",
    "react-multistep": "^5.1.0",
    "react-nestable": "^2.0.0",
    "react-number-format": "^4.9.1",
    "react-nvd3": "^0.5.7",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-photo-gallery": "^8.0.0",
    "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-simple-step-wizard": "^1.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-tag-autocomplete": "^6.3.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.4",
    "react-toast-notifications": "^2.5.1",
    "react-trello": "^2.2.11",
    "react-useinterval": "^1.0.2",
    "reactour": "^1.18.7",
    "recharts": "^2.1.9",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.8",
    "rodal": "^1.8.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.4",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^4.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8128  start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.6.0"
  }
}
```

My guess is the issue has something to do with the package.json code itself, but I'm not experienced enough in web dev to identify the root cause.

My most recent solution which worked with the project 1 package file was to use

1. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
2. `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`
3. `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
4. And then start the code with `npm start`

I tried to install the packages and run Project 1 with yarn, but was unable to get it to run. I tried to install project 2 with both npm and yarn, but both led to the issue listed at the top. Any insight would be appreciated.